# Do JUnit test suites support custom annotations?

Tags: java, reflection, junit, annotations, test-suite

In JUnit, you can create test suites like so:

```
public class SecurityTest1 {
    @Test
    public void testSecurity1() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class LoadTest1 {
    @Test
    public void testLoad1() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class SecurityTest2 {
    @Test
    public void testSecurity2() {
        // ...
    }
}

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({SecurityTest1.class, SecurityTest2.class})
public class SecurityTestSuite {}
```

But this seems rather cumbersome. It would be so nice to define a simple class-level annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface SecurityTest {}
```

And then define your suite like so:

```
@SecurityTest
public class SecurityTest1 {
    @Test
    public void testSecurity1() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class LoadTest1 {
    @Test
    public void testLoad1() {
        // ...
    }
}

@SecurityTest
public class SecurityTest2 {
    @Test
    public void testSecurity2() {
        // ...
    }
}

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({SecurityTest.class})
public class SecurityTestSuite {}
```

Is this possible? If so how? **Note**: not interested in switching to TestNG or any other test framework if JUnit does not support this...thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into implementing your own `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by implementing your own [Test Runner](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Test-runners) similar to the [Suite](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Suite.html) runner.

This runner should extract the marker annotation class from the value of the `@SuiteClasses` annotation (you should probably replace `@SuiteClasses` with your own annotation). Take a look at the `getAnnotatedClasses` method of the `org.junit.runners.Suite` class.
After having the marker annotation class, you should scan the classpath for test classes marked with this annotation (use a library such as [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/)) and pass an array of them to the appropriate Runner constructor.
 
You can find a similar behavior in the `Suite` constructor:

```
public Suite(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder) throws InitializationError {
   this(builder, klass, getAnnotatedClasses(klass));
}
```